# Ruby optparse behavior wrt InvalidOption vs MissingArgument exceptions

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, optparse

I have a ruby cli parsing script and it seems that there is some sort of regex behavior for parsing options:

```
op = OptionParser.new do |x|

      x.on("--output-config PATH", "The filesystem location for the output config file") do |output_config|
        options[:output_config] = output_config
      end

      x.on("-j", "--json", "If this is set, then json is output instead of tabular form") do 
         options[:disp_json] = true
      end

       x.on("-h", "--help", "Show this message") do 
        puts op
        exit 0
       end

       x.on("-v", "--version", "Show version") do 
         puts "version #{VERSION_NUMBER}"
         exit 0
       end
  end


  # do input validation and check leftovers for proper commands
  begin
  # parse options, parse! removes elements from ARGV so leftovers are positional arg(s)
    op.parse!(ARGV)
    options[:config_file] = ARGV[0] if ARGV[0]

  rescue OptionParser::InvalidOption, OptionParser::MissingArgument
    puts "###############  #{$!.to_s}  ###############"
    puts ""
    puts op
    exit 1
  end
```

Then if I call it as such:

```
script -a
```

It outputs the following (expected behavior)

```
###############  invalid option: -a  ###############
```

Or

```
script --output-config
```

It outputs the following (expected behavior)

```
###############  missing argument: --output-config  ###############
```

So this is where it gets odd:

```
script --output
```

It outputs the following (*not* expected behavior)

```
 ###############  missing argument: --output  ###############
```

Or

```
script --ou
```

It outputs the following (*not* expected behavior)

```
 ###############  missing argument: --ou  ###############
```

Basically anything you pass that regex matches "output-config" is passed to the block for

```
x.on("--output-config PATH"....
```

Which is the cause of the MissingArgument vs InvalidOption behavior I'm seeing.

Am I using optparse wrong or is this a bug in the library?

####### EDIT

If I add another x.on:

```
x.on("--out PATH", "The filesystem location for the output config file") do |output_config|
    options[:output_config2] = output_config
end
```

And pass either -o (one dash, ie a short form) or --o (two dashes), it does not throw an exception (I specifically am rescuing OptionParser::AmbiguousOption at the handling is not executed).  Instead is executes the shortest match, which is --out.  If I pass --outp, then the longer one is executed.  This seems flaky to me.

####### EDIT 2

```
> ./my_app --output-c
###############  missing argument: --output-c
```

The MissingArgument exception only displays the flag as passed, not as 'intended'.  It clearly knows that it is matching against '--output-config' so I'd like to be able to know that so that my error message to the user is clear and explicit.  Is there a way I can determine what optparser was matching against at the time that the MissingArgument exception was raised?

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior with long options. I'm having trouble finding any supporting documentation but I've been using this feature of long options as long as I've been using long options (i.e. since a long long time ago).

You can see it easily with the GNU version of **ls(1)**:

```
$ ls --h
ls: option '--h' is ambiguous
Try `ls --help' for more information.

$ ls --he
Usage: ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).
Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort.
...

$ ls --help
Usage: ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
List information about the FILEs (the current directory by default).
Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort.
...
```

There are multiple options that begin with `--h` so `--h` is an options error, there is only one option that starts with `--he` so `--he` is the same as `--help`.

If you add an `--output-pancakes` option, then you should get a complaint about ambiguity if you say `--output` but `--output-c` and `--output-p` will work.

You're not using the library incorrectly. Nor is this a bug. This is a feature.

Comment: But `--out` is different, `--out` is an exact match for an option so there is no ambiguity. If I add an `--output-pancakes PATH` option and just use `--output` then I get an `OptionParser::AmbiguousOption`. The parsing is intentionally fuzzy.

Comment: Ok just confirmed what you said being true.  What about the fact that it takes the short form for the long form automatically?  Also, if it is just a fact that optparse automatically attempts to match the option (ie --ou => --out) then when catching a MissingArgument exception, it would be nice to know which explicitly listed option the argument is missing from so the user can see the help menu and know which option had a required argument that they left off.

Comment: Can you update your question to cover your last comment so that I can see what you're doing?